# How can I improve the loading of this ASP.NET page that is using a WebService?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am a new user of WebService in .NET and I am struggling right now with the performance or the time of loading one page of the web applications that is using this web service.
This page has a dropdownlist that is listing a big number of items retrieved from the web service. That is why the Page_Load takes a long time as shown in the code below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
      itemDDL.Items.Clear();
      itemDDL.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select an Item", "0"));

      FillItemsInfo()
   }
}

protected void FillItemsInfo()
{
   DataTable dataTble = WS.GetItemsDetails();
   foreach (DataRow row in dataTble.Rows)
   {
      itemDDL.Items.Add(new ListItem(row["Item_NUM"].ToString(), row["Item_NUM"].ToString()));
   }
}
```

**Is there any way to let the system retrieving the items from the WebService at the moment when the user clicks on the dropdownlist to see the list of items?**
Please help me with this issue as I am struggling a lot with it and there is no resources about it.

Comment: you really have to reduce the amount of data coming back. does not matter which technique you use to populate the list, if the list is large then you will take a hit.

Answer (score 0):

> dropdownlist with a big number of items

It doesn't make sense. Look like you are retrieving a lot of items from web services.

Actually, you only want to retrieve the required items to display.

In other words, web service should use pagination using skip and take.